# Finding field lines given a plane vector field

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

**Problem:** Determine the field lines of the vector field \begin{align*} \mathbf{F}(x,y) = x\hat{i} + y \hat{j}. \end{align*}

The field lines satisfy the system \begin{align*} \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y}. \end{align*} Integrating gives \begin{align*} \ln|x| + A = \ln|y| + B, \end{align*} where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

I'm not sure how to proceed now, any help?

**Edit:** Exponentiating both sides, we get \begin{align*}e^{\ln(x)} e^A = e^{\ln(y)} e^B, \end{align*}, and so \begin{align*} x e^{A-B} = y. \end{align*} Can I now replace $e^{A-B}$ by another constant $C$, and conclude that the field lines are straight lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exponentiate on both sides and use $e^{A+ln|y|}=e^Ay$. Absolute value can be omitted because an exponential of any real number is positive.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you check my answer now, I edited at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, your answer is right. The constant $e^{A-B}$ can be replaced by another constant $C$. Therefore the field lines are straight lines.